# Make mapping relationship to three table using EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am student developer at C#. I have a question while making relationship to 3 tables. My tables are like this.

```
 public class ImdbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Cast> Cast { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CastRole> CastRole { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MovieCastRoleMapping> MovieCastRoleMapping { get; set; }

        public ImdbContext() : base("ImdbDbContext")
        {
        }
    }

    [Table("Movies")]
    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int movieId { get; set; }
        public string movieName { get; set; }
        public string movieYear { get; set; }
        public string movieLink { get; set; }
        public string movieImageUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual MovieCastRoleMapping MovieCastRoleMapping { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("CastRoles")]
    public class CastRole
    {
        [Key]
        public int castRoleId { get; set; }
        public string castRoleName { get; set; }

        public virtual MovieCastRoleMapping MovieCastRoleMapping { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("Casts")]
    public class Cast
    {
        [Key]
        public int castId { get; set; }
        public string nameSurname { get; set; }
        public string biography   { get; set; }

        public virtual MovieCastRoleMapping MovieCastRoleMapping { get; set; }

    }
```

I did not find a clear solution to make correct relation for 3 tables. When I tried to make it myself, I facing an eror like this:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'fkCastId' on type 'ImdbEntity.Models.MovieCastRoleMapping' is not valid. The navigation property 'castId' was not found on the dependent type 'ImdbEntity.Models.MovieCastRoleMapping'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

I know I need to set navigation property. Untill now, I was using EF DbFirst but I want to make it EF CodeFirst without using a diagram. Could you help me for fallowing class correctly ?

```
[Table("MovieCastRoleMappings")]
public class MovieCastRoleMapping
{
    [ForeignKey("castId")]
    public int fkCastId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("castRoleId")]
    public int fkCastRoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("movieId")]
    public int fkMovieId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's your purpose? One to one relationship?? Among which tables? Are you ok with using FluentAPI?

Comment: I want to make one to many relation with other tables using MovieCastRoleMapping. Fluent API might be ok. No problem. I just need a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ImdbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cast> Cast { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CastRole> CastRole { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MovieCastRoleMapping> MovieCastRoleMapping { get; set; }

    public ImdbContext() : base("ImdbDbContext")
    {
    }
}

[Table("Movies")]
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int movieId { get; set; }
    public string movieName { get; set; }
    public string movieYear { get; set; }
    public string movieLink { get; set; }
    public string movieImageUrl { get; set; }
}

[Table("CastRoles")]
    public class CastRole
    {
        [Key]
        public int castRoleId { get; set; }
        public string castRoleName { get; set; }   
    }

[Table("Casts")]
public class Cast
{
    [Key]
    public int castId { get; set; }
    public string nameSurname { get; set; }
    public string biography   { get; set; }
}

[Table("MovieCastRoleMappings")]
public class MovieCastRoleMapping
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int fkCastId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("fkCastId")]
    public virtual Cast Cast { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int fkCastRoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("fkCastRoleId")]
    public virtual CastRole CastRole { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public int fkMovieId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("fkMovieId")]
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

That's for the solution. Thanks for your interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the navigation properties and using the attribute wrong:

```
[Table("MovieCastRoleMappings")]
public class MovieCastRoleMapping
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int fkCastId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("fkCastId")]
    public Cast Cast { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int fkCastRoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("fkCastRoleId")]
    public CastRole CastRole { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int fkMovieId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("fkMovieId")]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I facing like that:
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
ImdbEntity.Entity.MovieCastRoleMapping: : EntityType 'MovieCastRoleMapping' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
MovieCastRoleMapping: EntityType: EntitySet 'MovieCastRoleMapping' is based on type 'MovieCastRoleMapping' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Yes, you need a [composite key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations) or fluent code. See modified.

Comment: I understand. When I check my dbContext's diagram on SQL server, I am facing a view like this `https://hizliresim.com/odJPmk`. Is it possible or is it true ? Because there are so many table columns than I wanted and created.

Comment: @EmreSert - You should post your solution to help others.

Answer (score 1):

FluentAPI gives more features to implement navigation properties in code-first approach. The below code implements a one-to-many relationship between `Movie` and `Cast` and a one-to-one relationship between `Cast` and `CastRole`:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int movieId { get; set; }
    public string movieName { get; set; }
    public string movieYear { get; set; }
    public string movieLink { get; set; }
    public string movieImageUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Cast> Casts { get; set; }
}

public class Cast
{
    public int castId { get; set; }
    public string nameSurname { get; set; }
    public string biography   { get; set; }

    public int MovieId { get; set;}
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }

    public int CastRoleId { get; set;}
    public virtual CastRole CastRole { get; set; }

}

public class CastRole
{
    public int castRoleId { get; set; }
    public string castRoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual Cast Cast { get; set; }
}



public class ImdbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cast> Casts { get; set; }         // Table name will be "Casts"
    public DbSet<CastRole> CastRoles { get; set; } // Table name will be "CastRoles"
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }       // Table name will be "Movies"

    public ImdbContext() : base("ImdbDbContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Setting primary keys
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
                    .HasKey<int>(x => x.movieId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cast>()
                    .HasKey<int>(x => x.castId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CastRole>()
                    .HasKey<int>(x => x.castRoleId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
                    .HasMany<Cast>(x => x.Casts)
                    .WithRequired(s => s.Movie)
                    .HasForeignKey<int>(x => x.MovieId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Cast>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.CastRole)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Cast);

        // Creating Model
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Comment: ı facing like that : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'EntityTypeConfiguration<Movie>.HasMany<TTargetEntity>(Expression<Func<Movie, ICollection<TTargetEntity>>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. ImdbEntity

Comment: check modified answer.  `.HasMany(x => x.Cast)` changed to `.HasMany(x => x.Casts)`

Comment: we are mising one trick. I will find a solution if we find one.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<Movie, Cast>' does not contain a definition for 'WithOne' and no accessible extension method 'WithOne' accepting a first argument of type 'ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<Movie, Cast>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ImdbEntity

Comment: @EmreSert whats your ef version?

Comment: I have v6.4.0 on my project.

Comment: The answer is implemented for EF6